# What does dense mean in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

- If $f, g$ are regular functions on a variety X, then the set of points where $f-g=0$ is closed and dense, hence equal to $X. $ Why is it dense and why does the closure of such a set satisfy the equation?
- An open subset of a variety is dense (which means that the closure of an open subset is the whole variety). Why is it dense?  Many thanks for your comment.

Comment: To the latter question: this is because a variety is irreducible as a topological space. If $U$ is open, then $\overline U$ and $X\setminus U$ are closed and cover $X$, so either $U$ is empty or its closure is $X$. For the former, this is clearly not the case for arbitrary $f,g$. Are you perhaps working through a proof of the statement "if $f,g$ are equal on a dense set, they are equal everywhere"? If so, this set is dense by assumption.

Comment: Your title and question are mismatched - are you actually interested in the meaning of dense in addition to the questions in your post? Secondly, you're missing important assumptions about $X$ and the locus where $f=g$ in your first question. If $g=f+1$, certainly they can't be equal anywhere.